# How display notifications on product page [PRESTASHOP 1.7]

Tags: notifications, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

How display notifications like these on [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KudOh.png) on product page ?
I tried use:

```
$this->context->controller->errors[] = $this->l('Some message');
```

But i cant display this errors on the screen

Comment: What is the context, front or back office?

Comment: Front, product page

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with product page you may modify ProductController.

You can make a test writing

```
$this->errors[] = 'testing';
```

before return.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 types of notifications avaliable for you in front office:

**success** - An action was performed and everything went well.

**error** - Something went wrong.

**warning** - Important notice the merchant should know about.

**info** - “just so you know”.

They are PHP arrays, and they hold messages as a string. In your example you should try putting something like this in your controller:

```
$this->success[] = $this->l('Information successfully updated.');
```

Source: [link](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/themes/reference/templates/notifications/)